# jQuery Find child Checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

I have a quick jQuery question:

I have the following type of table:

```
<table id="my_table">
  <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" value="24"></td>
   <td> Click Here To Check The Box </td>
   <td> Or Click Here </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

And in jQuery, I am attempting to select the corresponding checkbox in that row that was clicked.

```
 $("#my_table tr").click(function(e) { 
     $(this).closest(":checkbox").attr("checked", checked");
  });
```

But the above isn't working.  Any quick ideas on selecting the checkbox on the row that was clicked?  Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

EDIT: BEST SOLUTION AT BOTTOM

Assuming there's only one checkbox, I would attach the event to the `td` instead of the `tr`:

```
$('#my_table td').click(function(e){
  $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox:first').attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6kVUU/)

If you want to be able to uncheck the checkbox as well...

```
$('#my_table td').click(function(e) {
    var $tc = $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox:first'),
        tv = $tc.attr('checked');

    $tc.attr('checked', !tv);
});
```

This function needs to be applied to the checkbox as well to negate the default behavior.

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/EXVYU/2/)

EDIT: The solution is most reasonable method is to cancel the functionality if the target is an input: http://jsfiddle.net/EXVYU/5/

```
var cbcfn = function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() != "INPUT") {
        var $tc = $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox:first'),
            tv = $tc.attr('checked');
        $tc.attr('checked', !tv);
    }
};

$('#my_table td').live('click', cbcfn);
```

Comment: Thanks mVChr.  Great links to the example, and I like the uncheck ability as well.  Cheers!

Comment: Actually, I just had one updated question. I noticed that in this example, you can't even click the "checkbox" itself.  Any way to get around this?

Comment: Look at the example 2 again.  I fixed that.

Comment: Okay, sorry to complicate this more.  I appreciate your help.  Please check out: http://jsfiddle.net/EXVYU/3/  The table I'm loading is via Ajax, so I need to use the jquery live method.  But, my modified function does not appear to work.  Clicking the checkbox still doesn't work.  Click the <td> does work, however.

Comment: 4th time's a charm.  ;-)  Thanks for your help and patience.  Learned something new today.

Comment: @Dodinas please check code that double inverted comma in - attr("checked", checked"); is missing.

Comment: how to find a specific checkbox, not the first

Comment: @clockw0rk instead of `:first` you can use `:eq(4)` or whatever. See jQuery API docs.

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method finds the closest parent.

You really want to search child elemets, You can try the following:

```
 $("#my_table tr").click(function(e) { 
     $(":checkbox:eq(0)", this).attr("checked", "checked"); 
  });
```

basically you are searching for the first checkbox found in the table row

some reference

[jQuery :eq() selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

......

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#my_table tr").click(function(e) {
    state= $(this).find(":checkbox:eq(0)").attr("checked");
    if (state==true){ // WITH TOGGLE
        $(this).find(":checkbox:eq(0)").removeAttr("checked");
    }else {
        $(this).find(":checkbox:eq(0)").attr("checked", "checked");
    }       
});
```

I make simple script to check first checkbox in specific tr.
about toggle i just make it to try before post this answer.

Answer (score -1):

try this also...

```
 $("#my_table tr").click(function(e) { 
 $(this).closest("type:checkbox").attr("checked", checked");
});
```

Comment: This is just wrong as the jQuery closest() method works up the DOM tree.  Meaning it will find the closest parent that matches.